# How to bind Pane with another Pane in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, kotlin, fxml, autoresize

I'm finding the way that how to bind the size of a pane with the outer pane.

I could bind the size ofRectangle with Pane, 
But couldn't bind an inner pane (Red dotted rectangle) with outer pane (Blue dotted rectangle)

### Why I couldn't do it

It seems to be that `Pane` does not provide `bind` method for `widthProperty`

### Objects

- At least, bind width with `TextArea` of inner Pane with outer Pane
- I'll make many new tabs, therefore, I prefer to bind inner Pane with outer Pane rather than bind `TextArea` directly to outer Pane.

### Situation

[image]

- Blue and Orange rectangles are bound well with pane `dropPane`
- But Blue border pane's width should be the same size as a red border pane!

### My Sources

`main.kt`:

```
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
import javafx.scene.*
import javafx.scene.control.*
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle
import javafx.stage.Stage

import javafx.scene.layout.*
import javafx.scene.paint.*


fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    println("EntryPoint")

    Application.launch(PaneBindingTest().javaClass, *args)

}

class PaneBindingTest : Application() {

    private var tabCount = 0

    private fun generateNewTab (): Tab {
        val tab = Tab()
        tabCount += 1
        tab.text = "Tab$tabCount"
        val fxml = javaClass.getResource("fxml/Tab.fxml")
        val aTabPane: Pane = FXMLLoader.load(fxml)
        aTabPane.border = Border(BorderStroke(Paint.valueOf("Red"),BorderStrokeStyle.DASHED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT))
        tab.content = aTabPane
        return tab
    }

    override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {
        primaryStage.title = "EntryPoint"
        primaryStage.isAlwaysOnTop = true
        val fxml = javaClass.getResource("fxml/EntryPoint.fxml")
        val root: Parent = FXMLLoader.load(fxml)
        val scene = Scene(root)

        val epPane= root.lookup("#EPPane") as AnchorPane // Entry Point Pane
        val dropPane= root.lookup("#DropPane") as AnchorPane // Drop Pane
        val tabPane= root.lookup("#TabPane") as TabPane // Tab Pane
        val singleDropPoint= root.lookup("#ForSingle") as Rectangle // Single-ArchiveSet drop point
        val multiDropPoint = root.lookup("#ForMulti") as Rectangle // Multi-ArchiveSet drop point

        //epPane.background = Background(BackgroundFill(Paint.valueOf("Yellow"), CornerRadii(0.0), Insets(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)))
        //dropPane.background = Background(BackgroundFill(Paint.valueOf("Green"), CornerRadii(0.0), Insets(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)))
        tabPane.tabClosingPolicy = TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.ALL_TABS // or SELECTED_TAB, UNAVAILABLE
        tabPane.border = Border(BorderStroke(Paint.valueOf("Blue"),BorderStrokeStyle.DASHED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT))

        singleDropPoint.heightProperty().bind(epPane.heightProperty().divide(32).multiply(23))

        multiDropPoint.yProperty().bind(singleDropPoint.yProperty().add(dropPane.heightProperty().divide(4).multiply(3)))
        multiDropPoint.heightProperty().bind(epPane.heightProperty().divide(4))

        primaryStage.scene = scene
        primaryStage.show()

        val newTab = generateNewTab()
        tabPane.tabs.add(newTab)
        tabPane.selectionModel.select(newTab)

    }
}
```

`fxml/EntryPoint.fxml`

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="EPPane" prefHeight="640.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children>
    <TabPane fx:id="TabPane" prefHeight="640.0" prefWidth="1152.0" tabClosingPolicy="ALL_TABS" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="128.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
    </TabPane>
    <AnchorPane fx:id="DropPane" layoutY="128.0" maxWidth="128.0" minWidth="128.0" prefWidth="128.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <children>
            <Rectangle fx:id="ForSingle" arcHeight="16.0" arcWidth="16.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="360.0" width="120.0" stroke="#1100ff" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="8.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="4.0"/>
            <Rectangle fx:id="ForMulti" arcHeight="16.0" arcWidth="16.0" fill="#ff9d1f" height="240.0" width="120.0" stroke="#ff8800" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="8.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="4.0"/>
        </children>
    </AnchorPane>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

`fxml/Tab.fxml`:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <children>
      <TextArea fx:id="FilePaths" layoutX="4.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="128.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="72.0" />
      <RadioButton layoutX="14.0" layoutY="206.0" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Hash/Size only">
        <toggleGroup>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="AnalyzeMethod" />
        </toggleGroup>
      </RadioButton>
      <RadioButton layoutX="120.0" layoutY="206.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="FileName" toggleGroup="$AnalyzeMethod" />
      <RadioButton layoutX="200.0" layoutY="206.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Directory Structure" toggleGroup="$AnalyzeMethod" />
      <CheckBox fx:id="CheckDiff" layoutX="336.0" layoutY="206.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Show Diff" />
      <CheckBox fx:id="CheckSame" layoutX="420.0" layoutY="206.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Show Same" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="ComboBox" layoutX="840.0" layoutY="202.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
      <HBox fx:id="LabelBox" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="978.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="4.0" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I've found that almost the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018344/javafx-pane-in-pane-resizing), but no answer was there.

Comment: Your use of `AnchorPane` is probably hindering you; try using [other layouts](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/package-summary.html) that will size and position their children automatically (or create your own layout/use a 3rd-party library). In JavaFX, parents size their children based on available space and any constraints, children don't size themselves based on their parent. Also, you're using FXML strangely. If you need access to the UI objects then use a controller and inject them into appropriately named fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a binding to achieve this. The problem is the fact that you set the constraints for `maxHeight`/`maxWidth` to `USE_PREF_SIZE`, i.e. to a fixed value that can very well be reached when resizing the window. Remove those constraints to allow the `AnchorPane` to grow as necessary:

**Tab.fxml**

```xml
<AnchorPane minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    ...
</AnchorPane>
```

Furthermore I recommend avoiding the use of `AnchorPane`s, if you can avoid it. It's hard to achieve responsive layouts with this kind of layout. `VBox` and `HBox` would do much better jobs in this case.

**Example:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>

<VBox prefHeight="480.0"
    prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <padding>
        <Insets topRightBottomLeft="4" />
    </padding>
    <children>
        <HBox fx:id="LabelBox" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="978.0" />
        <TextArea VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" fx:id="FilePaths"
            prefHeight="128.0">
        </TextArea>
        <HBox spacing="10" minWidth="-Infinity">
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets top="5" left="0" right="0" bottom="0" />
            </VBox.margin>
            <children>
                <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true"
                    text="Hash/Size only">
                    <toggleGroup>
                        <ToggleGroup fx:id="AnalyzeMethod" />
                    </toggleGroup>
                </RadioButton>
                <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="FileName"
                    toggleGroup="$AnalyzeMethod" />
                <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false"
                    text="Directory Structure" toggleGroup="$AnalyzeMethod" />
                <CheckBox fx:id="CheckDiff" mnemonicParsing="false"
                    text="Show Diff" />
                <CheckBox fx:id="CheckSame" mnemonicParsing="false"
                    text="Show Same" />
                <Region HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" /> <!-- placeholder to grow/shrink -->
                <ComboBox fx:id="ComboBox" prefWidth="150.0" />
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Thanks, too much @fabian. I never imagine that maxWidth/Height with Infinity value could affect it. I'll study your advice.